# Compare Arraylist of Strings with String

Tags: java, android

I tried `Arrays.asList().contains(string)` to compare array items with string but return is false every time even emailid matches .

This is my array:

```
List<String> arraySE = new ArrayList<String>();

if(Arrays.asList(arraySE).contains(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL)))){
    user.setSelected(true);
} else{
    user.setSelected(isSelect);
}
```

Sample ARRAY:

```
 [user1@gmail.com, user2@gmail.com, user3@gmail.com]
```

NO ERROR, returning false

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please could you format your code more clearly? It's *very* hard to read at the moment. It would be really useful if you could provide a [mcve] as well. (There's a lot of missing information at the moment.)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Check if a string is contained inside the list?

Comment: `Arrays.asList(arraySE).contains` this can't be right, you already have a list, when you do that you create another list that has your existing list as it's only member. Just do `arraySE.contains`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primitive example that works correctly:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add("Hello");
        arrayList.add("Hola");
        arrayList.add("Hallo");

        boolean contains = arrayList.contains("Hello");

        System.out.println(contains);
    }
}
```

I would recommend that you debug through your code and especially see what `c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL))` returns.

Comment: it worked thank you, Do u have any idea why my method is not working

Comment: I don't think your method per se is not working, but something else in your code that we cannot see in your snippet here. a) The array list might be empty, b) as I wrote, `c.getString` might return an unexpected value, c) ...

Comment: same thing i implemented with contains method, it's working

Comment: I got it from @Oleg comment

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean isThere = Arrays.asList(yourArray).contains("test");

if(isThere){

}
else{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, your list in your example is empty.
Sencodly, you don't need to use `Arrays.asList(arraySE)`, because it is already a list.

You can simply use the contains function to check:

```
    List<String> arraySE = Arrays.asList("user1@gmail.com", "user2@gmail.com", "user3@gmail.com");


    if (arraySE.contains("user1@gmail.com")) {
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str[] = {"A","B","C","D"};
    ArrayList a = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(str));
    System.out.println(a.contains("A"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a list of strings, call contains on it. It will work if a match is found.

Why it is failing now is basically when you are calling asList the returned list is not a list of strings, so equals method works differently in that case.